# Arabic Font issue .Gap appearing in between letters

Tags: android, textview

I am using `dubai.ttf` font for my app
The font is of for web but in the app there is space between the letters.

I have tried Arab reshaper

> https://github.com/agawish/Better-Arabic-Reshaper

and

> https://github.com/smmoosavi/android-Farsi-Tools

showing like this image below

[image]

needed like this image below

[image]

and this is my code

```
AssetManager am = getActivity().getApplicationContext().getAssets();
        typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(am, String.format(Locale.US, "fonts/%s", "dubai_font.ttf"));

 mBtnShuffle.setTypeface(typeface);

mBtnShuffle.setText("اﻟﺗﺻﻧﯾفا اﻟﻘطﺎﻋﻲ");
```

Comment: Might be an issue with the font you are using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is not the correct solution but this is how i fixed my problem.
while using Arab language use `arial` font so far only this font had provided me with the correct arab words remaining fonts have space in between letters

Answer (score 0):

Hey Checkout [this link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:textScaleX),
Depending on how much spacing you need

or Use mBtnShuffle.setLetterSpacing(10);

Comment: i have tried it here just the spacing is reduced. i need to eliminate the gap and it support only from lollipop